# Re: Old bitcoin address fro BCH and BSV claiming

Tags: private-key, coldstorage, private-key-format

I have a BTC address from 2013 when I bought my BTC, it is a paper wallet (the BTC have been moved), but I want to claim my BCH and BSV (Is this correct I can also claim BSV?) and move it to my trezor.  It has been a looong time since I have done any of this and I am unsure how to do it now as it is in an old address and private key and I do remember a while ago reading somewhere that I have to convert an old address to a newer one to do this.

I have spent ages looking through forums etc but am no clearer - so does someone know where I can find this information on what to do?  If there is a video that would be brilliant... or if there is a wallet that would do the conversion for me - even better

Thanks in advance